# How should I document allowable array param values in php

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

Often I am passing an array as a constructor parameter.  How should I document the allowable values?  I have tried a few styles but they look a bit of a mess in phpdoc.

Comment: I think it might be better to explicitly define what parameters you want to receive as opposed to passing an array.

Comment: If you've got lots of params, consider building a separate object(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no "official" phpdoc way for documenting hashed arrays but here's one way:

```
/**
 * @param array $options hash of standard options for this class:
 *    int id the id of whatever object
 *    string name name of whoever it is
 *    array sub_option hash of sub options:
 *        int num number description for this index
 *    bool is_good should we do this or not?
 */
 function __construct( $options ){
 }
```